# Как просмотреть все записи в админке wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Скопилось около 35 записей. Мне нужно расставить их в определенном порядке (пользовательская сортировка) или просто вывести их на одной странице, не разбивая их по страницам. Не могу добиться этого результата. Как вывести в админке сразу все записи на одной странице, чтобы мне было легче править, а не переходить по страницам, ища нужную?

Comment: @harley, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wp-info.ru/admin-per-page-limits-kolichestvo-vyvodimyx-postov-na-stranice-v-adminke/

Или вот, без плагинов.

http://webgyry.info/kak-nastroit-kolichestvo-postov-stranits-na-odnu-stranitsu-v-admin-paneli-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

Идешь в раздел "Записи", в самом верху есть две кнопки "Опции экрана", "Помощь".
В Опциях есть настройка "На странице" и ставишь, сколько тебе нужно.